# Can you use Arrow Eruption to duplicate Arrow of Death?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, prestige-class

Arrow Eruptions states that:

> **You create exact duplicates of the arrow or crossbow bolt you used to kill a creature in the previous round** and launch one at enemy
>   creatures within a 30-foot radius of the corpse. You can target one
>   creature per caster level (maximum 15) within range of the burst and
>   must make a single attack roll and apply it to each arrow. **These
>   duplicate arrows possess all the intrinsic magical properties of the
>   arrow that killed the original creature** as well as those passed on
>   to it by your bow. They also enjoy the full benefit of any bonuses or
>   modifiers you applied to the attack from other magical items, feats,
>   and class or racial features. However, this spell cannot reproduce any
>   spells or other limited-use magical effects that you used to enhance
>   that particular attack. This includes such effects as the true strike
>   spell, as well as any area spell you might have placed on the arrow by
>   means of the arcane archer's imbue arrow class feature.

And Arrow of Death, an Arcane Archer (Prestige Class) ability states that:

> At 10th level, an arcane archer can create a special type of slaying
>   arrow that forces the target, if damaged by the arrow's attack, to
>   make a Fortitude save or be slain immediately. The DC of this save is
>   equal to 20 + the arcane archer's Charisma modifier. It takes 1 day to
>   make a slaying arrow, and the arrow only functions for the arcane
>   archer who created it. The slaying arrow lasts no longer than 1 year,
>   and the archer can only have one such arrow in existence at a time.

My question is, can you use Arrow Eruption to duplicate an Arrow of Death shot the last round? How will the two spells work with each other, if at all?

Comment: Jack's answer is correct, however you could purchase or craft  an Arrow of Slaying or Greater Arrow of Slaying, and Eruption on that. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you pick up the arrow out of the enemy corpse?

Comment: @thoth19 No, once an arrow hits a target it is considered destroyed, according to the core rulebook.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### No.

Funnily enough, it comes down to this line.

> and the archer can only have one such arrow in existence at a time.

This makes the arrow a

> limited-use magical effects that you used to enhance that particular attack.

which means the Slaying ability of the arrow is not duplicated by Arrow Eruption.

The intent is clear and would disallow this, and thanks to that line, the RAW is, too.

You would duplicate the enchantments on the arrow, any bonuses granted by your feats or class abilities that are not limited-use magical effects or spells, and otherwise treat the duplicated arrows as the arrow you used, but without the slaying property or any other limited-use abilities or spells applied to it.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, with a caveat:

> Magic Ammunition and Breakage: When a magic arrow, crossbow bolt, or sling bullet misses its target, there is a 50% chance it breaks or is otherwise rendered useless. A magic arrow, bolt, or bullet that successfully hits a target is automatically destroyed after it delivers its damage.

For Arrow Eruptions:

> You create exact duplicates of the arrow or crossbow bolt you used to kill a creature in the previous round

So, if you killed the creature (1st step necessary for Eruptions) the Slaying Arrow is destroyed, so you no longer have one in existence. However, I would limit it in that the Eruptions in that case would only be able to produce one slaying arrow and the rest would fail creation.

So, according to the RAW I would interpret it as being possible, however I would probably home rule against it as it would potentially be game disrupting.

Clarification for the rule:

> However, this spell cannot reproduce any spells or other limited-use magical effects that you used to enhance that particular attack. This includes such effects as the true strike spell, as well as any area spell you might have placed on the arrow by means of the arcane archer's imbue arrow class feature.

The arcane archer is making a generic (rather than the typical keyed to a creature) slaying arrow, which I would regard as an intrinsic characteristic, much like a +2 magical arrow, the +2 is intrinsic to the arrow as the slaying property is. If you can purchase and duplicate a +2 arrow, then by extension you can purchase and duplicate a typical slaying arrow. There is nothing different between the "regular" slaying arrow and one created by the arcane archer other than the ability of the archer to make it, rather than having to purchase one made for him.

Comment: How do you get around the ban on duplicating "limited-use magical effects that you used to enhance that particular attack" that Jack Lesnie used as a cornerstone of his answer?

Comment: @MrLemon - See clarification added.

Comment: Agreed -- the limited-use magical effect enhanced *the arrow* not *that particular attack*, and seems clearly in line with the kind of thing the eruption is designed to duplicate. I disagree that it would be all *that* disruptive; the Arrow of Death class feature only become available *very* late, when most things worth their salt are immune to death effects anyway, and arcane archers have paid dearly for the privilege of making those arrows (a minimum of 4 spellcasting levels for a half-BAB, full-spellcasting class).